# On submitting form with action post on a defined url, request is showing empty

Tags: django, django-forms

request.POST is showing empty.
therefore form is never validated.
do i need to do this by ajax call?

Here is the html and the view
HTML:

```
    <form action="{% url 'customer_form' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        <input id="first_name" type="text">
        <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
        <input id="last_name" type="text">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" type="email">
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        <textarea id="address"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
```

View:

```
    def customer_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            fname = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            lname = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            address = form.cleaned_data['address']
            Customer.objects.create(
                first_name=fname,
                last_name=lname,
                email=email,
                address=address
            )
            return HttpResponse('Customer Saved')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Not saved')
    else:
        return render(request, 'customer/customer.html')
```

Urls:

```
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^customer_form/', 
        views.customer_form,name='customer_form'),
        ]
```

Comment: Please format the code.

Comment: sorry, it is formatted now

Comment: Also paste your `urls` where `customer_form` is defined.

Comment: still getting empty POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given any of your inputs a `name` attribute, so no data will be submitted.

But you should be using the Django form to output them, in any case:

```
{{ form.first_name }}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on [@Daniel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) answer, **every form input element must have a `name` attribute defined,** otherwise that element will not be processed.

As per [**W3C form specification**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html):

**Users interact with forms through [`named controls`.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2)**

In its specification, it mentions the below for a `control` to be valid so that the field is received on the other end.

> **A successful control is "valid" for submission.** Every successful control has its control name paired with its current value as part of
>   the submitted form data set. A successful control must be defined
>   within a `FORM` element and **must have a control name**.

So an element must have a control name defined for it to be valid which means we need to give the input types in our form a `name` attribute for it to work properly.

> A control's `"control name"` is given by its `name` attribute.

You can do something like:

```
<form action="{% url 'customer_form' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text">
    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
    <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text">
    ...
</form>
```

You can also use `{{form.first_name}}` and Django will automatically render `first_name` as a input text field.